# Disable MatSort on space key pressed Angular Material

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

So I'm using angular material tables and decided to made a filter for each column. The inputs for this filters are located in the row header of each column. That works fine, but the thing is when I'm typing and pressed the space key, the table gets sorted. I want this behavior to stop, but if I used `(keydown.space)="$event.preventDefault()"` but the space isn't inserted in the input. Here is the code below of the table.

```html
<table mat-table class="full-width-table" (matSortChange)="sortData($event)" [dataSource]="this.datasrcCollIndex" aria-label="Elements" matSort matSortActive="strName" matSortDirection="asc" matSortDisableClear>

        <!-- Name Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="strName">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
                <mat-form-field style="margin-top: 0px;">
                    <input matInput placeholder="Name" (keyup)="filteringByColumns()"  [(ngModel)]="strName" >
                </mat-form-field>
            </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user">{{user.strName}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Gender Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="strGender">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
                <mat-form-field style="margin-top: 0px; width: 70px;">
                    <input matInput placeholder="Gender" (keyup)="filteringByColumns()" [(ngModel)]="strGenderColumn">
                </mat-form-field>
            </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user">{{user.strGender}}</td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="this.dictstrDisplayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row (click)="this.showDetailsOfUsers(user)"
            *matRowDef="let user; columns: this.dictstrDisplayedColumns;"></tr>

    </table>
```

Comment: Apply some regEX that no allow type continues space in input.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sayan, but can you elaborate more on your answer please? I don’t understand why I should use regEx just to stop an event from happening or is there something that I don’t get?

Comment: can you provide your code in stackblitz?

Comment: I made a quick stackblitz, I left out some functionality and styles, but the problem still shows, when you try to type in the row headers of the table and you press space, the sort arrow gets activated, making the data be sortable.https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dgc151

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using

```
preventDefault()
```

I used

```
stopPropagation()
```

it still allows input to be entered, but does not propagate the event to the parent elements (thus the sorting element never receiving the event).
Usage:

```
(keydown.space)="$event.stopPropagation()"
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem and did:

```
event.preventDefault();
(event.target as any).value += ' ';
```